# Which type of flute is this?

Tags: flute, instrumentation

Which type of flute is used in the soundtrack to the film Stalker composed by Edward Artemiev?

Music here:

Comment: Sorry, but identifying instruments is not what this site is about.

Comment: What is this site exactly about? Lilypond user support?

Comment: I mean, I’m pretty sure this is an instrumentation / orchestration question? But close away if you think it helps the site ‍♂️

Comment: At least move it to the right stack if you think there is one. Music fans?

Comment: @tomh Unfortunately this question doesn't fit any of the current stacks. It would also be off-topic in Music Fans. Consider asking in the chat room. There's a good chance you'll get an answer there.

Comment: @ojs and tomh, [this help page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalker_(1979_film)#Soundtrack) outlines the topics covered. Searching in [the Meta section for 'instrument identification'](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=instrument+identification) shows a lot of the discussion around why these types of questions haven't been covered.

Comment: By the way, the ["Soundtrack" section of the wikipedia article on the film](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=instrument+identification) talks about instrumentation. It seems to suggest that we're hearing a standard western flute along with an Azerbaijani *tar*, though I have my doubts. If it is a non-western instrument, perhaps it's one of the "musicians from Armenia and Azerbaijan," and a flute from those cultures.

Comment: @guidot Lol, thanks! [Here's the proper wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalker_(1979_film)#Soundtrack). By the way tomh, if you're generally interested in this non-classical flute style, it might be rewarding to investigate many of the other flutes. Some of the stylistic things we're hearing here can also be heard in the Persian ney, indigenous American flutes, the Japanese shakuhachi, and many others.